# got java.io.FileNotFoundException when app uninstall -> build again

Tags: android, file

i tried to save data to txt file, and read it again when open app, here is method im using:

```
public static void saveFcmListString(String data,Context context) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("fcmConfig.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "saveFcmListString File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static String getFcmListString(Context context) {
        String ret = "";
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("fcmConfig.txt");

            if (inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
//                    stringBuilder.append("\n").append(receiveString);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

as using above method i have fcmConfig file that contains some string, but when uninstall + install app again, i tried to write to file but i got this error

```
File not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/.../files/fcmConfig.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I read documents about file but can not sure that file is deleted after uninstall app?

Answer (score 1):

yes, when app is uninstalled then stored files in `/data` directory are also removed

newest Android versions prevent leaving any data when app is uninstalled

Comment: leaving any data in system which will be kept during uninstall-install process? thats not possible, not on current Android 11. one and only way is `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` [permission](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access), but if your app isn't created for managing files then it may be rejected from publishing in Google Play

Answer (score 1):

Yes all your apps private files are deleted too when you uninstall your app.

Store them at a different place to survive reinstalls.

Comment: hi, i tried Sharedpreference but still no luck, did it still work for external storage?

Comment: The shared preference will be gone too at uninstall. If you can put files on external storage they will surviive. But with Android 11 new problems arise.On Android 11 you can solve them without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. It very much depends on the Android version of the used device.